# Including trailing zeroes when formatting NodaTime instant?

Tags: c#, .net, nodatime

Using NodaTime 2.4.x

If I create an `Instant` that starts bang on a second, and then try and format it with a `Pattern` that includes milliseconds / nanoseconds, the trailing zeroes are cut off.

e.g.

```cs
using System;
using NodaTime;
using NodaTime.Text;

public class Program
{
    private static readonly InstantPattern _instantPattern 
            = InstantPattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture("uuuu'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss;FFFFFF'Z'");

    public static void Main()
    {
        var instantRound = Instant.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(158507100000);
        var instantNotRound = Instant.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(158507100001);
        Console.WriteLine(_instantPattern.Format(instantRound));
        Console.WriteLine(_instantPattern.Format(instantNotRound));
    }
}
```

Outputs

```
1975-01-09T13:45:00Z
1975-01-09T13:45:00.001Z
```

[You can see this here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Eiaor0)

Is there anyway I could get the output to be the following, preferably using an inbuilt method:

```
1975-01-09T13:45:00.000000Z
1975-01-09T13:45:00.001000Z
```

Basically, keep the trailing zeroes.

Comment: Does using `ffffff` work?

Comment: ... Yes it does. Well that was simple, feel like I've spent hours searching for that. Feel free to write up an answer and I'll set it as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refer to [this page](https://nodatime.org/2.4.x/userguide/localtime-patterns) for the pattern specifiers. `F` will cause the insignificant trailing digits to be stripped. `f` will not.

You also used the wrong method names. It should be `FromMillisecondsSinceUnixEpoch`, not `FromUnixTimeMilliseconds`.

```
private static readonly InstantPattern _instantPattern 
        = InstantPattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture("uuuu'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss;ffff'Z'");

public static void Main()
{
    var instantRound = Instant.FromMillisecondsSinceUnixEpoch(158507100000);
    var instantNotRound = Instant. FromMillisecondsSinceUnixEpoch(158507100001);
    Console.WriteLine(_instantPattern.Format(instantRound));
    Console.WriteLine(_instantPattern.Format(instantNotRound));
}
```

Comment: `uuuu` is usable in NodaTime, just has to be the latest. The docs you have linked are for `1.4.x` whereas the ones I were using were for `2.4.x`.

Comment: This is where I got the original formatting from:
https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime/blob/5ace09135d16a4ab7814b4c03b30ac6846b36d6a/src/NodaTime/Text/InstantPattern.cs#L53

I needed to limit the amount of precision to 6 after the seconds, but was still using the uppercase Fs.

Comment: @DanielEdwards I see. The documentation pages looked so similar... I should have been more careful... Anyway, edited.